Property 'mnumainmenu.Availability' of type 'object' has unknown object type 'mnumainmenu_Availability'
When I try to update my old realm model it shows this. and when I add new string properly to realm model it work perfectly but when i add list property this error shows.
**
Below you can see the Realm model**
import 'package:realm/realm.dart';
part 'mnu_main_menu.realm.dart';

@RealmModel()
@MapTo('mnumainmenu')
class _Mnumainmenu {
  @PrimaryKey()
  @MapTo('_id')
  ObjectId? id;

  @MapTo('CloudLocationID')
  String? cloudLocationID;

  @MapTo('IsDeleted')
  bool? isDeleted;

  @MapTo('ItemName')
  _MnumainmenuItemName? itemName;

  @MapTo('LocalID')
  int? localID;

  @MapTo('OrderIndex')
  int? orderIndex;

  @MapTo('ShowMenu')
  bool? showMenu;

  @MapTo('Availability')
  _MnumainmenuAvailability? availability;
}

@RealmModel(ObjectType.embeddedObject)
@MapTo('mnumainmenu_ItemName')
class _MnumainmenuItemName {
  @MapTo('Translations')
  _MnumainmenuItemNameTranslations? translations;
}

@RealmModel(ObjectType.embeddedObject)
@MapTo('mnumainmenu_ItemName_Translations')
class _MnumainmenuItemNameTranslations {
  String? en;
}

@RealmModel(ObjectType.embeddedObject)
@MapTo('mnumainmenu_Availability')
class _MnumainmenuAvailability {
  @MapTo('Sunday')
  late List<_TimeEntity> sunday;

  // Add other days as needed in the same pattern.
}

@RealmModel(ObjectType.embeddedObject)
class _TimeEntity {
  @MapTo('StartTime')
  String? start;

  @MapTo('EndTime')
  String? end;
}


I want to add new list property to my old realm model

mnumainmenu_Availability is an embeddedObject. .Availability is an object? Also, adding a property is generally non-destructive so there should be no issue doing that. Do you have a migration block somewhere?
